# slideToggle toggling twice

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I'm sitting here with a strange issue. Out of nowhere slideToggle started to toggling twice for me.

Here's the code:

```
$("div.comment_container").children("p").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("div.comment_box").slideToggle();
    });
```

and the html:

```
<div class="comment_container">
    <p>link</p>

            <div class="comment_box">
        <p class="comment_header"><?php echo $result2->author; ?></p>
            <p class="comment_content"><?php echo $result2->content; ?></p>
            <p class="comment_footer"><?php echo $result2->timestamp; ?></p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Div's are displayed relatively.
Any ideas what's the problem here?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/gttnU/

Comment: I would check the code as you may be registering the event twice. Save the Rendered HTMl and see if you can spot the event being registered twice.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oyiboh/1/edit works really well.

Comment: Hmm, i can see that. I suppose there is something with the css then.

Comment: try passing in `event` in the argument and stopping propagation to see if that does anything.  There might be some bubbling but not sure as there's not enough code to tell.  So `click(function(event) {` then inside `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: I've got no other events linked to this element. stop.propagation() had done nothing... Also, divs that are affected aren't inheriting any properties from their parents, all are aligned relatively.

Comment: pass in `event` in your click function.. then use `event.stopPropagation();`.. that was just a guess though..  Can you create a jsfiddle.net replicating your issue?

Comment: I've allready done it, without any succes. With jsfiddle this part of script is working fine. Nevertheless script and html are the parts of ajax result. I was thinking something was wrong with css, but the properties are just plain and simple.

Comment: Couldn't be the css.. it's your script.. something is triggering slidetoggle() twice

Comment: You were very right, ajax result was somehow duplicated and I didn't saw it. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I experienced the same issue as a result of my jQuery code being added to my page twice. Taking measures to ensure that my jQuery code is added once, resolved the issue with toggling triggering twice.